# Ionic + firebase Auth

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication

I'm using Ionic 1 and Firebase 3 in a personal project. I'm trying to apply the Firebase email and Facebook authentication on my apps. However, I'm new in this area and I'm not really good at debugging it.

I followed the tutorial on Firebase webs (sign up with email and Facebook login):

```
 // facebook
        $scope.signupFacebook = function () {

            console.log("in");
            var provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();

            firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function (result) {

                var token = result.credential.accessToken;
                var user = result.user;
                console.log(token);
                console.log(user);
                // $location.path('/tab/dash');

            }).catch(function (error) {
                var errorCode = error.code;
                var errorMessage = error.message;
                var email = error.email;
                var credential = error.credential;
            });

 $scope.signup = function (signupData) {

            console.log(signupData.value1);
            console.log(signupData.value2);
            console.log(signupData.email);

            if (signupData.email == null || signupData.password == null || signupData.username == null) {

                $scope.showAlertsignup();
            } else if (signupData.password != signupData.Confirmpassword) {
                $scope.showAlertsignupPass();
            } else if (signupData.password.length < 6){
                $scope.showAlertsignupPass();
            }else {

                 firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(signupData.email, signupData.password).catch(function (error) {
                // Handle Errors here.

                var errorCode = error.code;
                var errorMessage = error.message;
                // ...


                });

                var postData = {
                    "email": signupData.email,
                    "name": signupData.username
                };

                $http.post(url, postData).success(function (data) {

                });

                $scope.inscrireModal.hide();
                $location.path('/tab/dash');
            }

        }
```

The function `signupFacebook` works, but it doesn't apply the `$location.path('/tab/dash');`.

We are staying on the page with the button login with Facebook and I don't know why. If someone can explain to me the reason, that would be nice.

For the function sign up with email, it's the same problem. When I see on my Firebase account I see that I create a new client, but it don't going to the next page.

I'm starting in the development of mobile application, that's why if some of you have more experiences if possible can you give me some website or some keys to improve my skill in development of mobile application?

Comment: How does this function get invoked? How did you verify that the $location.path() code is run? What's in the debug console? See [creating an mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: This function is invoked as follow     <button class="button button-full button-calm  " style="filter:alpha(opacity=50);
 -moz-opacity:0.7;
 opacity: 0.7;
 background-color:#000; 
        font-weight: bold;" ng-click="signupFacebook()">Facebook</button>       click on the button will invoke the function. And for check $location.path() is running, i put console.log and i see the token and user in my console